# Require CoffeeScript files in the browser

Tags: coffeescript, config, require

I'm trying to get some options out of a separate `config.coffee` into my main `app.coffee`. The way I try doesn't work somehow, I'm only getting:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Here are my two files, I really hope you can help me out here.

```
# app.coffee
config = require './config.coffee'
console.log config.api_key

# config.coffee
exports.config =
  api_key: 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY'
```

Comment: Note you can omit the `.coffee` extension when passing file paths to `require`, but otherwise app.coffee looks fine, assuming as mu points out, you are running this under node.js as opposed to a web browser.

Comment: Yup, so @udo you are probably having a basic nuts & bolts problem and should consider revisiting the coffeescript and node.js tutorials to understand the differences between node.js javascript and browser javascript. It sounds like you are coding for node.js and then trying to execute in Firefox.

Comment: oh, I thought if I require another file and compile my `app.coffee` it gets included.. is there a way to do this or do I have to put everything in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> oh, I thought if I require another file and compile my app.coffee it gets included.. is there a way to do this or do I have to put everything in one file?

You might want to edit your question to specify this.

There are some projects that let you "require" files and introduce a build step to  concatenate and minify them into a single one. Not all of them follow the Common/JS module spec. You can also use AMD based tools to load files asynchronously.

### Sprockets

Which uses comments like `#= require jquery` to require other files and then compiles them into a single file. While it's aimed at Rack based apps, it has a command line tool which you can use to automate the process.

url: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets

### Snockets

This is based on Sprockets, but it runs on Node.js

url: https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/snockets

### Browserify

This is another Node.js based tool.

> Make node-style require() work in the browser with a server-side build step, as if by magic!

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

### Require.JS

This is AMD based, so it can load files asynchronously, but it also has an optimizer wich can concatenate files.

---

I'm sure there are many more. Each have their own way of doing things and you can make them work with CoffeeScript.

Comment: No. CoffeeScript can help you join and combine files with the `-j` option, but it doesn't support modules. When running on Node.js you can use modules, because node supports them.